# Removing coordinate system but not coordinates of raster?

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system

I have several TIF files which has SWEREF99TM projection. What I want is to remove the SRS but keep the coordinates/extents of the file.

When I look at the file with `gdalinfo`:

```
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["SWEREF99 TM",
    GEOGCS["SWEREF99",
        DATUM["SWEREF99",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6619"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4619"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",15],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3006"]]
Origin = (650000.000000000000000,7602500.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (2.000000000000000,-2.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  650000.000, 7602500.000) ( 18d40' 6.13"E, 68d29'41.24"N)
Lower Left  (  650000.000, 7600000.000) ( 18d39'53.05"E, 68d28'20.68"N)
Upper Right (  652500.000, 7602500.000) ( 18d43'45.66"E, 68d29'36.39"N)
Lower Right (  652500.000, 7600000.000) ( 18d43'32.36"E, 68d28'15.85"N)
Center      (  651250.000, 7601250.000) ( 18d41'49.30"E, 68d28'58.55"N)
Band 1 Block=1250x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=0
```

When I strip the file from SRS I'd like it to look something like this in gdalinfo:

```
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (367500.000000000000000,7010000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (2.000000000000000,-2.000000000000000)
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  367500.000, 7010000.000) 
Lower Left  (  367500.000, 7007500.000) 
Upper Right (  370000.000, 7010000.000) 
Lower Right (  370000.000, 7007500.000) 
Center      (  368750.000, 7008750.000) 
Band 1 Block=1250x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=0.010 Max=310.480 
  Minimum=0.010, Maximum=310.480, Mean=25.321, StdDev=73.974
  NoData Value=0
```

Can I do this preferably with GDAL?

Comment: how about `gdalinfo | tail -n +23`

Comment: Well it doesn't have to do anything to gdalinfo, I just used gdalinfo here to show that what I want is a geotiff with no projection, only coordinates.

Comment: in that case your question doesn't really make any sense, please add some explanation as to why you want to do this

Comment: You want the origin information and the corner coordinates to change as well? If the data is really still in SWEREF99 TM, you just need to re-georeference it.

Comment: @mkennedy, the data is Sweref99TM and the coordinates are right, but the tool I will be using for the files will not work if the files has projection set to it. I need to keep the corner coordinates.

Comment: Okay, got it. I missed that the 2nd one was a general example.

Comment: Possibly this way: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2010-November/026701.html

Comment: @mkennedy, perhaps you want to make a proper answer so I can give you credit for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this solution in a comment by @mkennedy works best for me:

```
gdal_translate -co PROFILE=BASELINE -co TFW=YES dem.tif dem_clean.tif
```

Answer (score 2):

The workaround that is described in the six years old gdal-dev mailing list post http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2010-November/026701.html and that was referenced by @mkenneny still works. However, since that GDAL has a new raster metadata editor gdal_edit http://www.gdal.org/gdal_edit.html which has an option that should be perfect for you.

> **-a_srs srs_def**:
>
> Defines the target coordinate system. This coordinate system will be
>   written to the dataset. If the empty string or None is specified, then
>   the existing coordinate system will be removed (for TIFF/GeoTIFF,
>   might not be well supported besides that).

With gdal_edit you can now clear just the projection info from the tiff file without a need to write all the image data first into an interim file and then to the final one.

```
gdal_edit.py -a_srs None your_image.tif
```

Comment: When I run this python script I get this error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/gdal_edit.py", line 274, in <module>
    sys.exit(gdal_edit(sys.argv))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/gdal_edit.py", line 191, in gdal_edit
    ds = gdal.OpenEx(datasetname, gdal.OF_RASTER | gdal.OF_UPDATE, open_options = open_options)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OpenEx'

Comment: I am not good at installing GDAL and Python. On Windows I have found  that 32-bit OSGeo4W installation with Python 2.7 usually just works.

Comment: I'm using Mac...